# Relay driver circuit causes 5V line to get pulled down

Tags: relay, mosfet-driver, short-circuit

**PLEASE NOTE**: The schematic is slightly wrong. It is a MOSFET in my circuit, not the BC850 BJT.
The actual part is: BVSS138LT1G

[Link to MOSFET part](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/on-semiconductor/BVSS138LT1G/3062043)

**Problem Summary:** In the circuit below, I'm turning on the relay by driving the gate of the MOSFET with a microcontroller GPIO pin - I believe it's 3.3V/12mA driving signal. However, when I do this my VDD_5V line becomes about 2.7V.

This seems like a fairly common relay driving circuit, so I'm mystified as to what is going on here!

My initial thought is add a resistor somewhere. I tried adding a resistor between the source of the MOS and GND but I can't get enough voltage for the relay to close (it needs 3.5V at least to open). I might try adding a resistor between pin 2 of the relay and the drain of the MOS, but this is on a PCB and it is tedious to cut traces so I want to be more certain of the approach to take.

The relay coil current from the specs is 74.9 mA (however when I turn it on with a power supply I get less than that... closer to 40mA).

[5V Supply Part](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/texas-instruments/LM22675MR-5-0-NOPB/1951960)

[Relay Part](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/omron-electronics-inc-emc-div/G5LE-14-DC5/280371)

**Schematic**
[image: Schematic]

**Layout**
[image: Layout]

Comment: Where does your 5V supply come from? Could you show the relevant part of the schematic?

Comment: @JonathanS. Yes certainly! Thanks for the quick reply. Here is a link to the part -> [5V Supply Datasheet](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/texas-instruments/LM22675MR-5-0-NOPB/1951960)

Comment: What happens to the input voltage of the buck converter when the 5V rail collapses? Also, does the FET get hot?

Comment: @JonathanS. The 5V buck converter is fed by another on board power supply (12V). It does not change when the rail collapses. 

I haven't done much thermal testing, but after a brief touch it doesn't seem more hot than normal. I can take a temperature probe to it later today

Comment: The problem is not in the relay driver. The buck regulator design is faulty and cannot provide enough current to the relay.

Comment: Hmmm interesting... would it damage other components or the buck regulator component further if I power the board on the 5V rail with an external power supply? That might be a good way for me to test that theory

Comment: It'll be fine if you supply 5V externally. Check that CR4 is installed correctly, by the way.

Comment: Your CR4 footprint looks suspicious ... Seems to me like it's backwards.

Comment: @brhans I don't think it's backwards, just a bit ambiguous. The beveled part and asterisk would indicate the cathode. The diode itself may be mounted backwards though.
Funny that all the other components have their pads labeled but that diode doesn't.

Comment: A quick way to check the 5V supply would be to put a 47 ohm resistor across it (easiest with leaded a one) and see if the voltage drops. This would be draw just over 100mA, which should be a little more than your relay circuit should draw. If it handles the resistor, it should handle the relay.

Comment: Pcb comments - your power tracks are too thin. Fatten them up - pcb tracks have resistance, capacitance and inductance. As well, your choice of relay needs slots cut in the pcb to give adequate creepage distance between the high and low voltage circuits. This is for electrical safety. And don’t use the autorouter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone curious about this - the problem was my buck converter. Unclear exactly what the problem was, but I'm assuming it was a faulty unit. I ordered a couple new ones to add and test.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain what was wrong with the buck converter.